# Passing data to JS from MVC

Tags: javascript, c#

Im having a hard time passing data from my C# controller to my dashboard.js file in order to draw an apexChart.

Im not gonna lie, im a bit of a newby to C#, and JS. I have had endless conversations with chatGPT but I cannot get this issue resolved.

My HTML looks as follows:

```
@model AppRat.ViewModels.AR_DashboardViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}


@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/@@highlightjs/cdn-assets/highlight.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/demo/highlightjs.demo.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/dashboard.js"></script>
    @* <script src="~/js/demo/chart-apex.demo.js"></script> *@
    <script src="~/js/demo/sidebar-scrollspy.demo.js"></script>
    
}
//some code thats not relevant


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-6">
        <div class="data-panel-300">
            <h3 class="mb-3 text-center">Applications Statistics</h3>
            <hr />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="">
                        <script>
                            var chartData = {
                                totalUsed: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.ChartData.totalUsed),
                                totalNew: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.ChartData.totalNew),
                                totalDemo: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.ChartData.totalDemo),
                                totalNtu: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.ChartData.totalNtu),
                                categories: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.ChartData.categories)
                                };

                                // Your chart initialization code here...
                        </script>

                        <div id="apexColumnChart"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-6">
        <div class="data-panel-300">
            <h3 class="mb-3 text-center">NTU's</h3>
            <hr />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="">
                        <div id="apexAreaChart"></div> //this can be ignored as I havent even tried to use this one yet
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then my dashboard.js is as follows:

```
/*
Template Name: HUD ASP - Responsive Bootstrap 5 Admin Template
Version: 2.2.0
Author: Sean Ngu
Website: http://www.seantheme.com/hud-asp/
*/

var handleRenderApexChart = function () {
    Apex = {
        title: {
            style: {
                fontSize: '14px',
                fontWeight: '600',
                fontFamily: app.font.bodyFontFamily,
                color: app.color.bodyColor
            }
        },
        legend: {
            fontFamily: app.font.bodyFontFamily,
            labels: { colors: app.color.bodyColor }
        },
        tooltip: {
            style: {
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontFamily: app.font.bodyFontFamily
            }
        },
        grid: { borderColor: app.color.borderColor },
        dataLabels: {
            style: {
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontFamily: app.font.bodyFontFamily,
                fontWeight: '600',
                colors: undefined
            }
        },
        xaxis: {
            axisBorder: {
                show: true,
                color: app.color.borderColor,
                height: 1,
                width: '100%',
                offsetX: 0,
                offsetY: -1
            },
            axisTicks: {
                show: true,
                borderType: 'solid',
                color: app.color.borderColor,
                height: 6,
                offsetX: 0,
                offsetY: 0
            },
            labels: {
                style: {
                    colors: app.color.bodyColor,
                    fontSize: '12px',
                    fontFamily: app.font.bodyFontFamily,
                    fontWeight: app.font.bodyFontWeight,
                    cssClass: 'apexcharts-xaxis-label',
                }
            }
        },
        yaxis: {
            labels: {
                style: {
                    colors: app.color.bodyColor,
                    fontSize: '12px',
                    fontFamily: app.font.bodyFontFamily,
                    fontWeight: app.font.bodyFontWeight,
                    cssClass: 'apexcharts-xaxis-label',
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // apexColumnChart
var apexColumnChartOptions = {
    chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Profit & Margin Chart',
        align: 'center'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            horizontal: false,
            columnWidth: '55%',
            endingShape: 'rounded'
        },
    },
    dataLabels: { enabled: false },
    stroke: {
        show: true,
        width: 2,
        colors: ['transparent']
    },
    colors: [app.color.theme, app.color.indigo, app.color.inverse],

    series: [
        { name: 'totalUsed', data: chartData.totalUsed },
        { name: 'totalNew', data: chartData.totalNew },
        { name: 'totalDemo', data: chartData.totalDemo },
        { name: 'totalNtu', data: chartData.totalNtu }
    ],
    xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        categories: @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.ChartData.categories))
    },
    yaxis: {
        title: {
            text: '$ (thousands)',
            style: {
                color: 'rgba(' + app.color.bodyColorRgb + ', .5)',
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontFamily: app.font.bodyFontFamily,
                fontWeight: app.font.bodyFontWeight
            }
        }
    },
    fill: { opacity: 1 },
    tooltip: {
        y: {
            formatter: function (val) {
                return "$ " + val + " thousands";
            }
        }
    }
};

var apexColumnChart = new ApexCharts(
    document.querySelector('#apexColumnChart'),
    apexColumnChartOptions
);
apexColumnChart.render();


/* Controller
------------------------------------------------ */
$(document).ready(function () {
    handleRenderApexChart();

    $(document).on('theme-reload', function () {
        $('#apexLineChart, #apexColumnChart, #apexAreaChart, #apexBarChart, #apexMixedChart, #apexCandlestickChart, #apexBubbleChart, #apexScatterChart, #apexHeatmapChart, #apexPieChart, #apexRadialBarChart, #apexRadarChart').empty();

        handleRenderApexChart();
    });
});
```

and the code in the controller is as follows:

```
        DateTime defaultStartDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
        DateTime defaultEndDate = DateTime.Today;
        List<DateTime> dateRange = GetDateRange(defaultStartDate, defaultEndDate);
        ViewBag.DateRange = dateRange;

        ViewBag.ChartData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            categories = dateRange,
            totalUsed = new List<int> { 44, 55, 57, 56, 61, 58, 63 },
            totalNew = new List<int> { 76, 85, 101, 98, 87, 105, 91 },
            totalDemo = new List<int> { 35, 41, 36, 26, 45, 48, 52 },
            totalNtu = new List<int> { 35, 41, 36, 26, 45, 48, 52 }
        });

        ///---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\\
        ///--- Chart Vars End                                                                                                                  ---\\\
        ///---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\\

        return View(viewModel);
}

    // This should allow you to set a date range
    private List<DateTime> GetDateRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        List<DateTime> dateRange = new List<DateTime>();

        for (DateTime date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
        {
            dateRange.Add(date);
        }

        return dateRange;
    }
```

I keep cycling between errors related to Invalid decorator, to issues with JasonConversions... but regardless of the things I try **with chatGPT's "help" i cannot get the chart do draw or display any data

Comment: Try logging the values of your Viewbag.ChartData and see what you are getting, I think the problem is the order of your script inside the DOM. I don´t think it´s correct. You should have done it after the HTML DOM tree loads. Little advice also, don´t take Chat GPT for granted :)

Comment: In your javascript I see `data: chartData.totalUsed`, `.totalNew`, etc. In your c# code I see these totals are actually lists of integers. You probably need to use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` to generate json for those lists like you did for `categories`.

Comment: @OrisSin, yeah I have used it before to solve some issues, but it seems its lacking some data for the newer versions of MVC.

Comment: @derloopkat, actually this line in the script categories: @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.ChartData.categories)) complains about invalid decorators, however I have tried to convert the lists just above the script in the dashboard.js file. ```var totalUsedData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('totalUsedData').value);
var totalNewData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('totalNewData').value);
var totalDemoData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('totalDemoData').value);
var totalNtuData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('totalNtuData').value);```

Comment: @SmokeyVanDenBerg the line is invalid there because this is a .js file but it should work in a view. Html helpers are server side.

Comment: @derloopkat, I removed it thanks, actually got it working now... seems ```<script src="~/js/dashboard.js"></script>``` just really wanted to be at the top in the view